# Validar input aceitando quantidade específica de letras e números em javascript "para um RA, ex: p3087748"

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Eu fiz uma validação no HTML  usando `pattern`, tentei colocar letras e números ao mesmo tempo. Mais creio que não tem como determinar o mínimo de letra e números.

Exemplo: Só uma "letra" e "sete números" nessa sequência.

No primeiro momento fiz assim, verificação de número e letras (se for diferente disso volta um erro).

```js
function check(inputvalue) {
    let teste = /^[0-9A-Za-z]+$/;
    
    if(inputvalue.value.match(teste)) {
      alert("Sucess");
    } else {
      alert("Fail");
    }
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputvalue">
<button onclick="check(inputvalue)">
 testando
</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claro que tem como determinar quantidades específicas.

Se quer uma letra seguida de 7 números, basta trocar a regex para:

```
/^[A-Za-z][0-9]{7}$/
```

Se quer definir a quantidade mínima e máxima, basta trocar o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit). Por exemplo, `{2,7}` para no mínimo 2 e no máximo 7. Ou ainda `{2,}` para no mínimo 2, sem limite máximo.

---

Outro detalhe é que o [método `match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) retorna um array contendo várias informações, como o trecho que foi encontrado, grupos de captura, etc. Mas se você não precisa dessas informações e só quer saber se a string corresponde à regex (ou seja, apenas "sim ou não"), pode usar o [método `test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), que retorna simplesmente `true` ou `false`:

```
let regex = /^[A-Za-z][0-9]{7}$/;
if (regex.test(inputvalue.value)) {
    // sucesso
} else {
    // falha
}
```

---

E esta regex pode ser usada no atributo `pattern` sem problemas:

```js
const campo = document.querySelector('#campo');

campo.addEventListener('input', () => {
  campo.setCustomValidity('');
  campo.checkValidity();
});

campo.addEventListener('invalid', () => {
    campo.setCustomValidity('O campo deve ter uma letra seguida de 7 dígitos');
});
```

```css
/* deixar borda vermelha enquanto o campo for inválido */
input:invalid {
  border: red 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="campo" type="text" pattern="^[A-Za-z][0-9]{7}$" required />
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Comment: Cara, desculpa pela mega demora! Maaas tudo ocorreu bem, deu certinho sim ( agradeço pela sua explicação )